# How to convert between ADTs with lenses in purescript?

Tags: purescript, lenses

This is code is a working but simplified example of what I want to accomplish. I want to map from one type wrapping records into another:

```
import Prelude
import Data.Lens
import Data.String as String

newtype AsString = AsString { names :: Array String }
newtype AsSize   = AsSize   { names :: Array Int }

_names = lens _.names (_ { names = _ })

to_sizes :: AsString -> AsSize
to_sizes (AsString s) = AsSize $ over (_names <<< traversed) String.length s
```

How do I do the same with lenses only and without unwrapping the record first?

When using a lens like `lens (\(AsString s) -> s) (const AsString)` for the original type I guess it expects the result to be of the original type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you would be happy about this answer as I'm also proposing a bit of refactoring here...
If you are not happy please let me know and I will try to provide code sample based on below lenses without touching your types ;-)

Are you able to accept changing `AsString` and `AsSize` as follows?

```hs
newtype Names a = Names { names :: Array a }

type AsString = Names String
type AsSize = Names Int
```

This refactoring will simplify operations a bit and makes your type a bit more reusable. I really recommend this talk about the power of type parameters: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHjIl81HgfE).

For `names` field we can create lens by using generic [`prop`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-profunctor-lenses/5.0.0/docs/Data.Lens.Record#v:prop) function.

Regarding `Name` type we should derive [`Newtype`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-newtype/3.0.0/docs/Data.Newtype#t:Newtype) instance at first (please notice quite specific syntax of this deriving - I think that `_` type compiler deduces by itself):

```hs
 newtype Names a = Names { names :: Array a }
 derive instance newtypeNames ∷ Newtype (Names a) _
```

This class provides `wrap` and `unwrap` methods which are used by [`_Newtype`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-profunctor-lenses/5.0.0/docs/Data.Lens.Iso.Newtype#v:_Newtype) lens. So we can just use `_Newtype` lens now.

Finally you should be able to compose these two. Here we go:

```hs
module Main where

import Prelude

import Data.Lens (over, traversed)
import Data.Lens.Iso.Newtype (_Newtype)
import Data.Lens.Record (prop)
import Data.Newtype (class Newtype)
import Data.String as String
import Type.Prelude (SProxy(..))

newtype Names a = Names { names :: Array a }
derive instance newtypeNames ∷ Newtype (Names a) _

type AsString = Names String
type AsSize = Names Int

_names  = prop (SProxy ∷ SProxy "names")

toSizes :: AsString -> AsSize
toSizes = over (_Newtype <<< _names <<< traversed) (String.length)
```

P.S.

I often write also this to simplify type inference if I'm modifying the same type:

```hs
_Newtype' ∷ ∀ s a. (Newtype s a) ⇒ Iso' s a
_Newtype' = iso unwrap wrap
```

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking about doing it like this, it's great to have an example as I was playing with `Generic` and `derive instance` today.

I have yet to learn what SProxy does and you kinda lost me on the PS, but this is very valuable learning material for me.

Comment: Are you @DerKastellan registered on slack channel #purescript or #purescript-beginners? We can discuss `SProxy` a bit further there - please ping me with direct message if you want ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found an answer through experimentation:

```
import Prelude
import Data.Lens
import Data.String as String

newtype AsString = AsString { names :: Array String }
newtype AsSize   = AsSize   { names :: Array Int }

_ToSize = lens (\(AsString s) -> s) (const AsSize)
_names  = lens _.names (_ { names = _ })

to_sizes :: AsString -> AsSize
to_sizes s = over (_ToSize <<< _names <<< traversed) String.length s
```

The `(const AsSize)` seems to "mirror" the original record into the new type.